# UWP - positioning ruler using matrix transform inside zoomable ScrollViewer

Tags: matrix, uwp, matrix-multiplication

I have InkCanvas inside a zoomable ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled">
    <Border Height="5000" Width="5000" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
          <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas"  />
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want to position ruler to the top left corner.
Ruler is positioned on the `InkCanvas` and state of ScrollViewer is defined by by `HorizontalOffset`, `VerticalOffset` and `ZoomFactor`

I've found this code ([sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SimpleInk/cs/Scenario7.xaml.cs))

```
void OnBringIntoView(e)
{
    // Set Ruler Origin to Scrollviewer Viewport origin.
    // The purpose of this behavior is to allow the user to "grab" the
    // ruler and bring it into view no matter where the scrollviewer viewport
    // happens to be.  Note that this is accomplished by a simple translation
    // that adjusts to the zoom factor.  The additional ZoomFactor term is to
    // make ensure the scale of the InkPresenterRuler is invariant to Zoom.

    Matrix3x2 viewportTransform =
        Matrix3x2.CreateScale(ScrollViewer.ZoomFactor) *
        Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset,
           ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset) *
        Matrix3x2.CreateScale(1.0f / ScrollViewer.ZoomFactor);

    ruler.Transform = viewportTransform;
}
```

in short:

```
viewport = Scale(zoom) * Translate(offset) * Scale(1/zoom)
```

This works, but I'm a bit lost.

What does the first scale do and what does the second? Why can't I use juct TranslateTransform?

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I use juct TranslateTransform?

Because the [InkPresenterRuler.Transform property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkpresenterruler.transform.aspx) is designed to be  [Matrix3x2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.numerics.matrix3x2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> What does the first scale do and what does the second?

`Scale(zoom)*Scale(1/zoom)` aiming at letting the ruler be invariant to Zoom. No matter what your current zoom level is, the ruler will return to it's original size.

`Translate(offset)` changes the translation values(offsetX and offsetY) of the  transform Matrix.

For details of the transformation theory you can refer to:

**Remarks** of [Matrix Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Affine transformations** section of [Transformation matrix Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).